# Yii2 Date Range Search

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i got this error when create date range search in search model.

> Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column
>   'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

here's my model

```
 public $start_date;
    public $end_date;
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['attachment', 'id_client', 'delete_on', 'created_at', 'created_by', 'updated_at', 'updated_by', 'from_location', 'to_location','printed_at', 'lock','verify','verify_by','approved','approved_by'], 'integer'],
                [['policy_num'], 'autonumber', 'format'=>'formatPolicy'],
                [['policy_num','premium_policy'], 'string'],
                [['start_date','end_date'], 'date', 'format'=>'dd-MM-yyyy'],    
                [['from_location', 'to_location'], 'string', 'max' => 55],
                [['location_address'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
                [['attachment'], 'required'],
                [['deductible'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
                [['lock'], 'default', 'value' => '0'],
                [['lock'], 'mootensai\components\OptimisticLockValidator']
            ];
        }
```

here's my search model

```
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['id', 'policy_num', 'attachment', 'id_client', 'delete_on','created_by', 'updated_by', 'printed_at'], 'integer'],
                [['cover_rate'], 'number'],
                [['start_date','end_date','created_at','updated_at'], 'date','format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd'],
            ];
        }

        public function search2($params)
            {
                $query = AskPolicy::find();
                $query->joinWith(['client'])->where(['id_client'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id_client]);

                $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $query,
                ]);

                $this->load($params);

            if (!$this->validate()) {
                // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
                // $query->where('0=1');
                return $dataProvider;
            }

            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,
                'policy_num' => $this->policy_num,
                'ask_policy.created_at' => $this->created_at,
                'ask_policy.updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
                'printed_at' => $this->printed_at,
            ]);

    //         $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'ask_policy.created_at', $this->start_date]);
//         $query->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'ask_policy.created_at', $this->end_date]);

            $query->andFilterWhere(['like',"(date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at` ), '%Y-%m-%d' ))", $this->start_date])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', "(date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(`updated_at` ), '%Y-%m-%d' ))", $this->end_date]);

            return $dataProvider;
        }
```

if i use below code : search start date and end date not working

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'ask_policy.created_at', $this->start_date]);
$query->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'ask_policy.created_at', $this->end_date]);
```

how to the best way convert integer datetime in Yii2 for date range search ? i was searching but not find tutorial with good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is joined with `client` and both models has `created_at` field.
you can set alias for current model with

```
$query->alias('t');
```

and alias joined table with

```
$query->joinWith(['client as cli']);
```

then if you want to use `created_at` from main model you can use `t.created_at` and if you want to use `created_at` from joined model you can use `cli.created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

you have not given table alias try like this

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like',"(date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(ask_policy.`created_at` ), '%Y-%m-%d' ))", $this->start_date])
->andFilterWhere(['like', "(date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(ask_policy.`updated_at` ), '%Y-%m-%d' ))", $this->end_date]);
```

Comment: can you give me a query ?

Comment: SELECT
 ask_policy.policy_num,
 ask_policy.id_client,
 ask_client.insuranced_name,
 ask_policy.created_at
FROM
 ask_client
 INNER JOIN ask_policy
  ON ask_client.id = ask_policy.id_client
WHERE
 ask_policy.created_at BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date ;

Comment: can you put your database sample data and query with $start_date and other date value

Comment: i think my problem is because my created_at is use integer

Comment: yes but have converted in date. it is fine so pls give me a query what is it is become in last with my ans ?

Comment: SELECT
 ask_client.insuranced_name,
 ask_policy.policy_num,
 ask_policy.created_at
FROM
 ask_client
 INNER JOIN ask_policy
  ON ask_client.id = ask_policy.id_client
WHERE
 ask_policy.created_at BETWEEN 1490979942 and 1491056037
. insuranced_name, policy_num and created_at column :
 After Morning                       20170329021 1490979942 |
 After Midnight                       20170493041  1491056037 |

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140146/discussion-between-knowledge-and-sudo-ee).